# Asterisk in zsh Git info

Tags: visual-studio-code, zsh

I use my terminal to run stuff like `npm run start` while I use the terminal in VSCode for `git` commands. On my laptop, this worked perfectly, however after setting up zsh on my other device, there's something I've never noticed:

On my terminal: `~/Desktop/... | master *1`
On VSCode's terminal: `~/Desktop/... | master *2`

What do the numbers after `master` mean? This has caused me to pointlessly debug for 1 hour after releasing, if I do `npm run start` on my terminal, any changes on VSCode does not hot reload and apply the change. On the other hand, if I run `npm run start` in VSCode, it works normally.

It seems as though each shell is working on a different version of the current branch. Any idea what the asterisks mean? Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Depending on your prompt theme (I use powerlevel10k), this could indicate how many slots you have used in the stash. You can check this with:

`git stash list`

and if necessary remove them with

`git stash clear`

Comment: The stash is usually represented by `$`.

Comment: It depends on your terminal, I use powerlevel10x which represents stash as * this may be useful for others.

Comment: P10k is not a terminal. It's a _prompt theme_ for your _shell._

Comment: I'm leaving this answer here as it may help others, if you disagree please vote to close it

Comment: My last comment was not about disagreeing, but about your incorrect usage of terminology. You are right that the symbols mean something different in Powerlevel10k. I've now added a note about that to my answer.

Comment: As for me I'm expecting stashed when I see asterisks (I do not know why. Someone trained me). But I know `If something is stashed, then a '$' will be shown next to the branch name`. Also sometimes `git stash list` returns nothing for **powerlevel** but `git stash clear` cleans asterisks from the prompt.

Comment: @MarlonRichert yes that's a fair point, noted for future ref.

Comment: Thank you so much, Neil! Those asterisks with numbers have been driving me INSANE!

Answer (score 0):

I came across this exact same issue, *1 in my case was "stashed" changes I kept. Removing the using GitKraken delete stash, worked.