# What does the "main *1" in github repo mean?

Tags: git, oh-my-zsh

I did some changes to my repo some weeks ago and my repo constantly shows me a "*1" and I don't know the meaning of it. I'm just familiar with add, commit and push method and would like to solve this.

[image: CLI Output]

Comment: that's not a git question and it's not a github question.  you have something installed for your shell that decorates the prompt like that.

Comment: read the manual? https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/plugins/gitfast/git-prompt.sh

Answer (score 0):

It means you have 1 modified file on your repository that hasn't been staged yet (on *main* branch).

More info in this already answered [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67669788/asterisk-in-zsh-git-info#answer-67672625).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the dupe; next time it'd be better to also VTC as a dupe

Comment: I don't get your comment. Is there anything else I should have done?

Comment: Instead of answering, vote to close the question as a dupe if you know that a similar question covers the exact same ground.  There's no difference between the answer you're citing and where we're directing the OP to.